How do I add an animation to the sidebar navigation in ReactJs?
Ok so,
I m trying to build a Google Gemini clone and I have manged to make the UI except that i cannot get the sidebar to "smoothly" scroll in when I click the menu icon, it happens instantly. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? I m not sure if I should add the CSS transition property or something else, already tried it on the .sidebar class but it is not working.
Here is the code I tried so far:
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Sidebar.css'
import { assets } from '../../assets/assets'

const Sidebar = () => {
    const [extended, setExtended] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            <div className="top">
                <img onClick={() => setExtended(prev => !prev)} className='menu' src={assets.menu_icon} alt="" />
                <div className="new-chat">
                    <img src={assets.plus_icon} alt="" />
                    {extended ? <p>New Chat</p> : null}
                </div>
                {extended ?
                    <div className="recent">
                        <p className="recent-title">Recent</p>
                        <div className="recent-entry">
                            <img src={assets.message_icon} alt="" />
                            <p>What is react ...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div> : null}
            </div>


            <div className="bottom">
                <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
                    <img src={assets.question_icon} alt="" />
                    {extended ? <p>Help</p> : null}
                </div>
                <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
                    <img src={assets.history_icon} alt="" />
                    {extended ? <p>Activity</p> : null}
                </div>
                <div className="bottom-item recent-entry">
                    <img src={assets.setting_icon} alt="" />
                    {extended ? <p>Settings</p> : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar

Sidebar.css
.sidebar{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #f0f4f9;
    padding: 25px 15px;

}

.sidebar img{
    width: 20px;
}

.sidebar .menu{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .new-chat{
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #e6eaf1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .recent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar .recent-title{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .recent-entry{
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #282828;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .recent-entry:hover{
    background-color: #e2e6eb;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar .bottom{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar .bottom-item{
     padding-right: 10px;
     cursor: pointer;
}


The problem you have is that you render the navigation only when 'extended' is true. Adding a transition will not affect this since the element can not transition if it doesn't exist. What you could do is to just push the element off screen instead of not rendering it. This can be done in multiple ways, but the easiest way is to apply position: relative to the sidebar and updating the left (or right, depending on where the nav is) value to something that will push it off screen.
.offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px
}

Next to animate it, you'll simple need to add a transition on the left (or right) property. Make sure you don't add it to the .offscreen class, because this way it will only animate coming out, not sliding back in.
.sidebar{
  ...
  transition: left 1s
}

Hope this helps
